# Animate CO2 motor in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to recreate this engine in  Matlab: http://www.animatedengines.com/co2.html. I am looking to use handle graphics in order to animate all of the moving parts. I have all of the stationary parts already programmed. Right now I am working on getting the ball to move up and down, but I cannot figure out how it works. I don't have a very clear understanding of how handles work and what I need to do to get the ball to move. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this question really about programming or mechanic ?

Comment: @hivert: Sounds to me like a question regarding handle graphics in Matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example for a small circle moving around a larger circle:

```
%# create large-circle coordinates
t = 0:pi/100:2*pi;
xc = cos(t);
yc = sin(t);

%# create small-circle coordinates
xs = 0.1*cos(t);
ys = 0.1*sin(t);

%# plot large circle
figure,plot(xc,yc,'r');

%# plot small circle at first position
%# and capture handle
smallCircleH = plot(xs+xc(1),ys+yc(1),'b');

%# loop to update the handle of the small circle
for tIdx = 1:length(t)
   %# update position of small circle
   set(smallCircleH,'xData',xs+xc(tIdx),'yData',ys+yc(tIdx));
   %# wait a bit to appreciate the beauty
   pause(0.1);
end
```

Comment: Is it possible to move multiple objects using only one set command? For example, could you make another small circle moving in the opposite direction as the original circle using on one set command?

Comment: @user3320530 From the help of `set`: `set(H,pn,MxN_pv) sets n property values on each of m graphics objects, where m = length(H) and n is equal to the number of property names contained in the cell array pn. This allows you to set a given group of properties to different values on each object.`